# Javascript - affect object2 behavior so that if object1 is in OFF then object2 does not react to clicks

Tags: javascript

I started to learn Javascript, I'm trying to affect object2 behavior so that if object1 is in OFF then object2 does not react to clicks.
I'm trying to disable the function for object2 base on the stage of object one.
here is the code - but it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

object 1: ON/OFF switch using a boolean - no problem there.

object 2: once you click on the object - the user is asked to type a number and the object2 size change according to the user input.

My problem is to get object2 to react base on the ON/OFF switch from object1  so that if object 1 is OFF then object2 does not react to clicks and if the status is ON - object2 should react to clicks

```
function click() {                 //object 2
  var userinput = prompt("type a number ")
  var userinputnum = Number(userinput)
  var object2 = document.querySelector('.Object2')
  
  if (userinputnum <= 1000) {
    object2.style.width = userinputnum
    object2.style.height = userinputnum
    } else {
        alert('Too Big!')
    }
    if (Switch == true) {           //Switch = the boolean from object1
      object2.style.width = userinputnum
      object2.style.height = userinputnum
    } else {
    object2.style.width = 100
    object2.style.height = 100
    }
}
```

Hope I expressed myself better (sorry, its my first time here)

Comment: without a [mcve], we cannot really help much. Please consider adding a live demo ([mcve]) so we could follow along.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.